# How to reduce cached memory used by Linux kernel on embedded linux platform

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I have booted Linux within 32 MB of SRAM and looking to optimize the cached memory used by Linux kernel.
after login to command prompt, I see almost 8 MB memory was consumed by cached memory by Linux kernel.
From my explore I saw cached memory is used when we have disk io operations but in my case initramfs unpacked inside SRAM itself. so as per my understanding I can reduce this memory w/o any impact on performance correct me in case I missed something to understand.

[image: memory_usage]

Query 1:
Is there way to control this limit using some kernel config itself or way before we reach to user space?

I came across the userspace ways to control it but I didnt see its working for me, Do i need to enable any specific kernel config option which will make below command effective
I tried below commands.

```
   sync && echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
    sync && echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
    sync && echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

see the console outputs of below commands.
[image: cache_use_command output]
Query 2:
I have also disabled CONFIG_SHMEM from kernel, which helped me to reduce shared memory section in free command as 0(earlier it consumed nearly 6 MB). Is there any impact of disabling CONFIG_SHMEM on drivers of my system?

Comment: `drop_caches` means any reads of the dropped data will have to got to disk rather than already have the data in cache.  That will only reduce performance if you need to re-read that data.  There is no case where it will improve performance.

Comment: Does the system run entirely from initramfs or does it use switch_root?

Comment: Please, avoid using pictures where text is needed! Downvoted for this.